# I have two values in a Tuple like ('Type', 'RES') can i assign like Type=RES and store it in dict?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

```
(u'Type', u'RES')
(u'CustomerId', u'1110566212417')
```

is there any way to assign the Type = Res and store it in collection

Comment: You need to take more care with your question. What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `dict` constructor (it takes a list of tuples and makes a dict):

```
pairs = [
    (u'Type', u'RES'),
    (u'CustomerId', u'1110566212417')
]
collection = dict(pairs)

In [1]: collection
Out[1]: {u'CustomerId': u'1110566212417', u'Type': u'RES'}
```